# Пагинация, как исключить ОДИН из результатов?

Tags: php, sql, пагинация

Всем привет! Сделал пагинацию с помощью LIMIT и OFFSET в sql запросе. Проблема вот в чем:

Имеется набор статей на сайте, выводятся через foreach из базы данных. В базе есть Одна статья (id=12), которая должна НЕ показываться зарегистрированным пользователям. Цель показывать на каждой странице 8 статей. Как результат имею вот такой код:

```php
<?php elseif(isset($_COOKIE["active_user"])): ?> // Показывается зарегистр пользователям
<?php 
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; // добавляем гет парам, если его нет
    $limit = 8; // лимит на вывод статей
    $offset = $limit * ($page - 1); // Выссчитвыеам OFFSET
    $posts = get_posts_all($limit, $offset); // Функция, принимаюшая параметры
    foreach ($posts as $single):
        if($single["id"] == 12){
            continue; // пропускаем статью, которая не доступна зарегистрированным
        }  ?>
<a href="/post.php?id=<?php echo $single[" id "] ?>">
 <!-- тело статьи -->
</a>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

В результате и восьми статей одна выпадает (что ожидаемо). и остается семь, что

Но, задача, сделать так, что бы даже при "выпадающей" статье, на странице выводилось 8, тоесть подгружалась статья с id 13, например!

Подскажите пути решения!
Ниже, так же прикрепляю sql запрос

```php
// получение всех статей
    function get_posts_all($limit, $offset) {
        global $pdo;
        $posts = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM shop ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
        return $posts;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если есть такая возможность исключите в самом запросе:

```
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE id != 12 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
```

Например:

```
function get_posts_all($limit, $offset) {
      global $pdo;

      $where = isset($_COOKIE["active_user"]) ? '`id` != 12': '1';

      $posts = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM shop WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
      return $posts;
 }
```

Уточнение: Это пример. Я бы на Вашем месте не доверял кукам (Показатель, авторизованный пользователь или нет). Так-же ознакомился с [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Помогло!

Comment: Рад быть полезным ;-)

Comment: у меня все запросы, которые связаны с пользовательским вводом защищены через PDO prepare! Внутренние же запросы работают на прямую) Буду благодарен, если дадите ссылочку, на статью с правильной авторизацией на сайте, без печенек)

Comment: Куки всё-таки можно сбросить или переназначить. Может лучше использовать сессии?

Comment: Спасибо, @Quazimorda буду учиться) У меня сейчас по всему сайту натыканы $_COOKIE, буду углубляться в этот вопрос)